# obj.templatedMemFun<1>() parse error

Tags: c++

Here is my simplified code:

```
template<unsigned Size>
class Sequence
{
public:
    template<unsigned N>
    Sequence<Size - N> chop() const;
};

template<unsigned Size>
Sequence<Size - 1> chop1(Sequence<Size> const& seq)
{
    return seq.chop<1>();
}

int main()
{
    Sequence<2> seq;
    chop1(seq);
}
```

Since I didn't provide a body for `Sequence::chop()` it's not going to link, but it should still compile. Well, it doesn't and I don't understand why. I get the following compiler output:

```
$ g++ -c test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘Sequence<(Size - 1)> chop1(const Sequence<Size>&)’:
test.cpp:12:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     return seq.chop<1>();
                        ^
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Sequence<(Size - 1)> chop1(const 
Sequence<Size>&) [with unsigned int Size = 2u]’:
test.cpp:19:14:   required from here
test.cpp:12:20: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved 
overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
     return seq.chop<1>();
                    ^
```

So, the compiler doesn't seem to realise `Sequence::chop()` is a templated member function. When that happens with types, you can nudge you compiler with an explicit `typename`. Is there a similar trick for templated member functions?

Comment: `return seq.template chop<1>();`

Comment: @LogicStuff Is there a name for this technique? I'd like to read about it.

Comment: You have a good chunk of text to read in the duplicate's answer. After that you'll understand perfectly.